# Accessing code behind variable from aspx - what is wrong with this code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, webforms

I have a property in my code behind. My code is set up like this:

```
Protected url As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.DataBind()
    url = string.Format("'page.html?param1=paramValue1&param2={0}'", paramValue2)
    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        'some legacy code
    End If
End Sub
```

I want this url to be passed as the parameter of a javascript function which gets called on clicking a table row item:

```
<tr onmouseover="m_over()" onmouseout="m_out()" id="Link" runat="server" onclick="m_click(<%# url %>)">
    <td class="menu-item">
        Link
    </td>
</tr>
```

At runtime this is what my page source looks like:

```
<tr id="Link" onmouseover="m_over()" onmouseout="m_out()" onclick="m_click(&lt;%# url %>)">
    <td class="menu-item">
        Link
    </td>
</tr>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<%= ... %>` syntax instead of `<%# ... %>` and insert `onclick=...` into it like that:

```
<tr id="LinkSiteStaff" onmouseover="m_over()" onmouseout="m_out()" <%= "onclick=m_click(" + url + ")" %>>
```

Comment: I added single quotes to the code behind variable value. Should I remove those?

Comment: Also when I change it to <%= %>, I get a warning in Visual Studio that "This is not scriptlet. Will be output as plain text."

Comment: @Corpsekicker As I see, no, you should not add additional single quotes. My fault. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the syntax just gives me "onclick="m_click(&lt;%= siteStaffUrl %>)"

Comment: @Corpsekicker can you post more code from yours `aspx.vb` file code?

Comment: @Corpsekicker Try that snippet: `<tr id="Link" onmouseover="m_over()" onmouseout="m_out()" <%= "onclick=\"m_click(" + url + ")\"" %>>`. Hope it will help you. If so I'll update my answer.

Comment: Removing runat="server" meant that the Link object was not accessible from code behind.This isn't a disaster, I can probably get around it. What is interesting though, is that the resulting html looks like this: onclick='m_click('page.html?param1=param1Value&param2=')' and I get an error that says "Main.aspx:165 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" which tells me it doesn't like the string formatting?

Comment: Actually, I tried removing the formatting now and replacing it with a hard coded string, and I get the same result.

Comment: @Corpsekicker Replace single quotes to the `\"` as I wrote in my previous comment

Comment: Replacing the single quotes gives me: Compiler Error Message: BC32017: Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.